# How to calculate on which page a product should appear?

Tags: javascript, math

Let's say I have `72` products and each page can have up to `24` items. We know that we will have `3` pages thanks to this, but how can I calculate this mathematically? Let's say the input is `5` how do I calculate that product `5` is on page `1`, and product `48` on page `2`? Keep in mind that I have thousands of products and while the number of pages are irrelevant, each page may only have `24` items.

Comment: How you will have `2` pages. `72/24 = 3`

Comment: ... My bad, I have no idea how I did not see that.

Comment: You could simply keep subtracting 24 from the product number, and keep a counter for each time you could subtract 24 from the product number (the result after the subtraction being >= 0). The counter will tell you which page the product is in.  Or, you can divide the product number by 24, and the result will also give you the page in which the product is (without the decimals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just maths.  How many times the number of products per page can fit into the total product count.

I've assumed some variables with obvious names are around, but some JS code could look something like this:

```js
let totalProductCount = 1234;
let productsPerPage = 24;
let wantedProduct=48;

//Total page count would be the number of times the products per page
//can fit into the total, rounded UP if not a whole number.
let totalPossiblePageCount =Math.ceil(totalProductCount/productsPerPage);

//so same calculation can give the page NUMBER for a given product number.
let pageForThisProduct = Math.ceil(wantedProduct/productsPerPage);

alert (`product ${wantedProduct} will be on page ${pageForThisProduct}/${totalPossiblePageCount}`);
```

This will say "product 48 will be on page 2/52", and changing the value of `wantedProduct` will change appropriately